# error of downloading an application published by VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish, windows-server-2008-r2

This question is related to my previous question.

I need to publish an application built by C# on VS 2010 (.NET 4.0) to a Windows server 2008 R2.

I just followed the instructions ("publish to a file share or path") here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx

Now, the UNC path specified in the publish profile can be accessed. It is a location of a remote server.

But, in the browser, I can open the link:

```
\\serverName\e$\myPath\publish.htm
```

There is an install button on the webpage, it points to

file://serverName/e$/myPath/setup.exe

When I clicked it, it downloaded setup.exe to

```
C:\Users\myname\Downloads
```

When I ran it, I got:

```
 * Activation of C:\Users\myName\Downloads\myApp.Host.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
 + Downloading file:///C:/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp.Host.application did not succeed.
 + Could not find file 'C:\Users\myName\Downloads\myApp.Host.application'.

 System.Net.WebException
    - Could not find file 'C:\Users\myName\Downloads\CWIL.Host.application'.
```

But, the

```
  myApp.Host.application
```

has been created at:

```
 \\serverName\e$\myPath\Application Files\myApp.Host_2_1_6_7
```

Did I miss something here ?

Any help would be appreciated.